# SSRS 2008 adjacent group row height not same as the other adjacent group's

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i'm doing some work on SSRS report that require adjacent group.
The problem is the row height of above adjacent group appears bigger than the the other group below it.
Both row height are 0.14pt.
There is no cell in both row that has row height bigger than 0.14pt.

this is in design page:

[image]

and this is in web page:

[image]

as you can see the difference in row height.

i would like the row height to be the same for both group.

how do i do that. please help

thanks!

*EDIT*

here is hierarchy of row group for this table/matrix

[image]

and here is some illustration of how the table is arranged in html.
the blue cell is in same `<tr>` and yellow is in another `<tr>`
(<s>*you can manage to picture the html code i believe*</s>)

[image]

Comment: This looks like the css in your web page is conflicting with the report. Go on the web page check the styling via F12. There must be an ID or name that one row has that the other doesn't.

Comment: This is what i discovered:

- the above group is part of `<tr>` from parent group for these two adjacent group.

- the below group is in another `<tr>`

- both tr have this extra td that have these inline style: height,colspan,rowspan. both is at first td.

- the parent+above group's first td have height=9.1mm

- the below group has height=3.56mm

- as both below and above group is initially set with same height i assume both should be 3.56mm

- this bring an extra height: 9.1-(3.56*2)=1.98mm

- this probably the extra height appeared on the above group.

Comment: is this by design?

Comment: @Snowlockk please refer extra info after the 'edit' above sir.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Can grow Property to False.. and ensure the column width is wide enough to accommodate expected values in the box.. and ensure consume container  white space is set to true on the report properties..

Comment: i've set width to be bigger *double the width to 1.0 pt*. consume container space to true and CanGrow properties to false. it still showing the gap. any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Select the group row in design and go to properties (left side pan)
Under General option there is property as CanGrow, set it to False.

[image]

Comment: tried that and putting CanShrink to False make the row height bigger.

Comment: Set CanGrow Property to false to lock your cell height. i gave the screenshot just to locate where those properties are.

Comment: ive put CanGrow to false, the row height still showing extra height.